# Delphi: Differences in Heights etc in dfm file between two developers

Tags: delphi, height, difference

We are running Rio version 10.3.3. When 2 different developers save the dfm file for the mainform, 
we see in our GIT client ( SmartGIT ) that there are lots of differences, specially according to Height on Labels etc.

The TextHeight and Height properties are 14 for me, and 13 for the other developer. Does anyone know the reason for this, and what to do to solve the problem ?

We have tried to start with a new Delphi project, and added all the units for the origin project into this, but the result is the same.

When doing https://dpi.lv/, we both have the same value 166 pixels/inch.

On MainForm:

```
Scaled = true,
ClientHeight = 786,
ClientWidth = 1405,
Height = 845,
Width = 1421,
PixelsPerInch = 96,
Position = poDesigned
```

Comment: I'm guessing two mentioned developers use different setting for UI scaling in Windows. Or one have screen resolution big enough for windows to start using scaling and another doesn't.

Comment: Are you both using Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, we both use Windows 10.